# How do I search Twitter for a specific hashtag? API's

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I am trying to understand how I can do the following;

Search Twitter for a specific hashtag used in the last 24 hours, eg- list all #london tweets in the last 24 hours..

Thanks,

I've been using tweetsharp and it doesnt seem to work

```
service1 = new TwitterService   

var tweets2 = service.Search("#london", 10)

tweets1 = service.Search("#Test", 100);

Console.WriteLine(List<TwitterSearchStatus> resultList = 
              new List<TwitterSearchStatus>(tweets1.Statuses););
```

I'm sure it's just oudated but any help would be appreciated, i've just started learning api's so be easy :)

I'm using c# in vs 2013 btw

Comment: Please make sure that the code you post is at least compilable

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: It is compatible.. It works with c#..whats the issue? and a link does help-please dont comment if you will just be so useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        // Pass your credentials to the service
        TwitterService service = new TwitterService("App_ConsumerKey", "App_ConsumerSecret");
        service.AuthenticateWith("accessToken", "tokenSecret");

        SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#specifichashtag", Count = 100, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Recent };
        var searchedTweets = service.Search(options);
```